# Make programmatic range selection visible to the user?

Tags: javascript, dom, select, range, visible

How can I make a programmatical page selection visible to the user, as if it was selected by the user?

```
var range = document.createRange();
var startPar = [some node];
var endLi = [some other node];
range.setStart(startPar,13);
range.setEnd(endLi,17);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```